# How to define a continuous map from $[0,1] $ onto/into $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

It is possible to define a continuous map from $[0,1]$ onto $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}. f(x) = 0$. Oh sorry, I read into not onto... No a surjective, continuous map is not possible.

Comment: @ HendryXT) By the way constant function can not be into...

Comment: It's a theorem that any continuous function with domain $[a,b]$ is bounded. This is slightly weaker than the Extreme Value Theorem, which states that the image has a maximum (that is, the image isn't something like $[0,1)$ which doesn't have a highest element).

Comment: Actually, once you show that it's bounded, you can prove the full Extreme Value Theorem; the main idea is to consider the function $\dfrac1{M-f(x)}$ where $M$ is the supremum of the image of $f$.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Well. The constant function $f:\Bbb R\to\{0\}$ is onto (that is, onto $\{0\}$). But, yes, if the codomain has more than one point it's not onto.

Comment: When the domain has only one point the it is into...

Answer (score 3):

You can't define such a continuous map.

**Hint :**

$\bullet$  $[0,1]$ is compact but $\mathbb R$ is not.

$\bullet$  If $f$ is **onto** then $f([0,1])=\mathbb R$.

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: Oh yes. Continuous image of a compact set is compact. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello sir.. i have a doubt. Suppose i consider R with indiscrete topology. Then both empty set and R are only open sets in R... Thus every possible open covering of R with respect to this topology has a finite subcover... so i am thinking, in this situation R is compact... is i am right? plz clarify..

Comment: @AvinashN $\Bbb R$ with the indiscrete topology is compact, yes. With that topology, though, _every_ function $[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: @ Avinash N ) Yes....You are right...$\mathbb R$ is compact with respect to discrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the continuous image of a compact space is compact -- but $\mathbb R$ is not compact.

Note: The "onto" means $\mathbb R$ must be the image of the map. That's where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I assume by "onto $\mathbb R$" you mean a surjective, continuous map from $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$. You might want to take a look at the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).